# Algorithm for detecting random filenames?

Tags: algorithm, random, filenames

Can anyone think of an algorithm that would detect random filenames? For example, a human could tell that the filename "SKJJSMIJ.EXE" looks like it was randomly generated versus a filename like "winsetup.exe" or "Photoshop.exe", but how can a program determine this? Thanks!

Comment: trying to detect virus which runs as windows process "hjdd.exe"? If you are, then judging a file by its filename is a bad bad idea.

Comment: It could be for a quite valid reason - eg auditing organisation policy on file naming standards?

Comment: @Russell In that case there are "standards" so you can check the filename using "standards" but detecting randon file name is almost impossible.

Comment: What if the standards said what the PO said: " human could tell that the filename ... [not] randomly generated"

Answer (score 5):

Well what if `SKJJSMIIJ` comes from `society of knights juggling juniors, skunks, mascots, idiots, introverts and jockeys` ? Then it would be a legitimate filename. Also consider a name like `Eyjafjallajökull.jpg`. This will look like a random filename, but is in fact the name of an icelandic volcano.  You could make an algorithm that detects unpronounceable filenames, but it will give MANY false positives.

Comment: Actually, at least in the various sets of evaluations I mentioned in my answer, `Eyjafjallajökull` probably wouldn't look like a random filename. Among other things, the non-base64 character and the `Xxxxx` capitalization scheme are unlikely elements in random filenames.

Answer (score 2):

If you're really getting into depth on this, there are a few different items you could try:

1. Look for dictionary words. If a filename contains a dictionary word of length ~4 or more, chances are it's not random.
2. Look for consonant/vowel patterns - if a file has lots (3+) consonants in a row, it's more likely to be random. On the other hand, if there are almost never more than 2 consonants/vowels in a row, it's less likely to be random.
3. Look at capitalization. If there are odd patterns of capitalization (like `XxXXx` or `xxXxXX`) there's a decent chance it's random. On the other hand, if it follows a very neat pattern of capitalization (like `Xxxxx`, `XxxxxXxxxXxxxx`, or similar), it's much less likely to be random.
4. Look at unlikely character pairings. Break down the filename into pairs of adjacent letters (so `"abcd.txt"` becomes `['ab', 'bc', cd']`), and compare the frequency of occurrence of each of those pairs with a pre-computed set of values for normal filenames. This is similar to checking for dictionary words but doesn't require a comprehensive dictionary (and can also be trained on things like proper names).
5. Look for patterns of numbers versus letters - filenames with very mixed numerical and alphabetical portions (especially those without separators in between them) are likely random.

No method will be foolproof, but if you combine many of these heuristics together to devise an overall score, you might be able to get a "good enough" approximation.

Answer (score 1):

In the examples you gave, the "non-random" filenames both contain English words, while the "random" filename does not. I think a good starting heuristic for "randomness" as you seem to define it would be to check substrings of the filename (before the extension, of course) to see if they match the words in a reasonably-sized dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Well, of course, it will depend on the target language but, for English, I can't think of *any* words off the top of my head that have two `J` characters in a row, nor any that have three of any character in a row.

You might also look for groupings that have a preponderance of characters from one part of the keyboard, like `ewrwqr` or `bvnvxbnx`.

Or, examine the consonant to vowel ratio both for the word and sections of the word.

That might be a good start but no method will be foolproof.